# Можно ли как то с формы которая находится на tilda, отправить запрос на heroku

Tags: post, запрос, heroku, tilda

Можно ли как то отправить данные с формы на tilda, сразу в приложение на heroku?

Comment: https://help-ru.tilda.cc/formsscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

help-ru.tilda.cc/formsscript  - решение проблемы в этой ссылке.
Проблема была в том что я не верно подключал приложение на хероку, поэтому тильда не хотела с ним взаимодействовать.